# C++ noob getting seg faults

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Making a vector of lists of unsigneds in C++. I am clueless when it comes to pointers but I think I need to declare the vector as holding pointers to the lists.

It's just been a disaster. If it compiles at all, I get seg faults.

I don't know in advance how large the vector will be until I get a file to read (it should be on the first line) and I won't know how large the lists will be until i get through the file.

Any ideas on how to declare the vector of lists? I think once I get that I can figure out the rest (OK maybe not but I'll be closer). Thx.

Comment: `vector<vector<unsigned>>` would be a good starting place.  You can write this program (or, at least, the parts of it that you describe here) without having to use any pointers in your code.

Comment: A `vector` of `list`s to `unsigned int`s ought to be fine, as @JamesMcNellis says. If this is truly the problem section of code, it is likely because you are accessing out-of-bounds range (e.g. by using operator[] past the end of the length of the vector).

Comment: In which case using `at` instead would assure you if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a debugger to trace the location of the crash.
- Never make a vector of raw pointers; use smart pointers only if you absolutely must have a vector of pointers.
- Vectors do the memory management and resizing for you.

  `vector<list<TYPE> > vecOfLists; //empty`
  `vecOfLists.push_back (some_list); //add new list onto the back`

If you're using lists in place of an ordinary array, you might be better off using a vector of vectors instead.

Comment: I just got home and I like these answers although I haven't tried them yet. For the vecOfLists, the 2nd line is adding an empty list, but I won't know in advance whether each entry in the file will require a new list or adding onto a list I just made, so I don't think that will work. At least I don't know how to make it work... hmmm.

Comment: If you need a new list, use `vecOfLists.push_back (the_new_list);`. If you need to add onto one, use `vecOfLists [index_of_list_to_add_onto].push_back (additional_element);`

Comment: Maybe I can loop n times and make an empty list for each n (which I'll know at the top of the file) then go through the file adding to the correct list. Each line of the file will have an initial value that tells me the index of the list to put the rest of the line in. There may be multiple lines with the same index. I just have to figure how to access that list ... If an entry is "index addx", would it be something like vecOfLists[index].push_back(addx)?

Comment: CAN'T THANK YOU ENOUGH! I got it all working and found my "debugging" scheme to print the values after assigning them were causing seg faults too.